# How do I reference data from a parent element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I would like to reference the data-post-id of a parent div when clicking on an achor:

```
<div data-post-id="5">
 <a data-vote-type="1">Like</a>
 <a data-vote-type="2">Dislike</a>
</div>
```

To reference the vote-type, I can do this:

```
var voteData = '&voteType=' + $(this).data('vote-type')
```

But I would also like to include the post-id in the `voteData` var. I'm not sure how to do this however. I have multiple posts on the page, each with their own like/dislike buttons!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [`$(this).parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

If you need a specific ancestor, you should call [`$(this).closest('selector')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), which finds the innermost ancestor that matches a selector.

Comment: SLaks, thanks for that. If I want the parents parent, would I do this: $(this).parent().parent().data() ?

Comment: @Mel: Yes, you could.  However, it would probably be better to call `.closest` with a selector that matches the element you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var voteData = '&voteType=' + $(this).data('vote-type') + '&postId=' + $(this).parent().data('post-id');
```